# Are two lines in $\Bbb R^2$ always homeomorphic when the topology on them is induced by $\mathcal{T}$?

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the sets $[a,b) \times [c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R$ and $a<b, c< d$ form a basis for some topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\Bbb R^2$. Are two lines in $\Bbb R^2$ always homeomorphic when the topology on them is induced by $\mathcal{T}$?

For the first part of the problem I get that for any $x \in \Bbb R^2$ there exists $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R$ such that $x \in [a,b) \times [c, d)$. Thus the collection $\{[a,b) \times [c,d) \mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R\}$ covers $\Bbb R^2$.

Also for $B_1, B_2 \in \{[a,b) \times [c,d) \mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R\}$ and $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ we have that $x \in ([a,b) \times [c,d)) \cap ([e,f) \times [g,h)) \implies x \in [e,b)  \times [g,d)$ which is an element of $\{[a,b) \times [c,d) \mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R\}$ implying that the sets $[a,b) \times [c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R$ and $a<b, c< d$ form a basis for some topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\Bbb R^2$.

I don't understand the second part. Are we considering the two lines as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ with each having the subspace topology of $\mathcal{T}$ that's generated on $\Bbb R^2$ by the basis $\{[a,b) \times [c,d) \mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R\}$?

Comment: Yes, consider a line as a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is really trivial: a standard fact (in Munkres' text) is that this collection is in fact a base for the product topology on $\Bbb S \times \Bbb S$ where $\Bbb S$ is the set $\Bbb R$ with as a base for its (Sorgenfrey, hence the $S$ name) topology all sets of the form $[a,b), a < b$ (Munkres calls this the lower limit topology, but that's his quirk, all other topologist calls it the Sorgenfrey line after its "discoverer"). The product space is known as the *Sorgenfrey plane*.

And the line $y=x$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb S$ again and the line $y=-x$ is a discrete space of size continuum. So very non-homeomorphic.

Comment: Why is $y=x$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb S$? It looks as if I can only get lines that are of form $y=-x$ as the right top and bottom corners in the generated topology aren't considered.

Comment: @LocomotRagsar you can consider any line equation. It’s a general fact that the diagonal of a square $X^$ is homeomorphic to $X$.